# Matlab - Eliminating for loops

Tags: matlab, for-loop

So, I am aware that there are a number of other posts about eliminating for loops but I still haven't been able to figure this out.

I am looking to rewrite my code so that it has fewer for loops and runs a little faster. The code describes  an optics problem calculating the intensity of different colors after the light has propagated through a medium. I have already gotten credit for this assignment but I would like to learn of better ways than just throwing in for loops all over the place. I tried rewriting the innermost loop using recursion which worked and looked nice but was a little slower.

Any other comments/improvements are also welcome.

Thanks!

```
n_o=1.50;
n_eo=1.60;
d=20e-6;
N_skiv=100;
lambda=[650e-9 510e-9 475e-9];
E_in=[1;1]./sqrt(2);

alfa=pi/2/N_skiv;
delta=d/N_skiv;

points=100;
int=linspace(0,pi/2,points);
I_ut=zeros(3,points);
n_eo_theta=@(theta)n_eo*n_o/sqrt(n_o^2*cos(theta)^2+n_eo^2*sin(theta)^2);

hold on

for i=1:3

    for j=1:points
        J_last=J_pol2(0);
        theta=int(j);

        for n=0:N_skiv
            alfa_n=alfa*n;
            J_last=J_ret_uppg2(alfa_n, delta , n_eo_theta(theta) , n_o , lambda(i) ) * J_last;
        end

        E_ut=J_pol2(pi/2)*J_last*E_in;
        I_ut(i,j)=norm(E_ut)^2;

    end

end

theta_grad=linspace(0,90,points);

plot(theta_grad,I_ut(1,:),'r')
plot(theta_grad,I_ut(2,:),'g')
plot(theta_grad,I_ut(3,:),'b')
```

And the functions:

```
function matris=J_proj(alfa)
matris(1,1)=cos(alfa);
matris(1,2)=sin(alfa);
matris(2,1)=-sin(alfa);
matris(2,2)=cos(alfa);
end


function matris=J_pol2(alfa)
J_p0=[1 0;0 0];
matris=J_proj(-alfa)*J_p0*J_proj(alfa);
end


function matris=J_ret_uppg2(alfa_n,delta,n_eo_theta,n_o,lambda)

k0=2*pi/lambda;
J_r0_u2(1,1)=exp(1i*k0*delta*n_eo_theta);
J_r0_u2(2,2)=exp(1i*k0*n_o*delta);
matris=J_proj(-alfa_n)*J_r0_u2*J_proj(alfa_n);

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you cannot get rid of a for-loop if you are doing a calculation that depends on a previous answer, which seems to be the case with the J_last-variable.

However I saw at least one possible improvement with the n_eo_theta inline-function, instead of doing that calculation 100 times, you could instead simply change this line:

```
n_eo_theta=@(theta)n_eo*n_o/sqrt(n_o^2*cos(theta)^2+n_eo^2*sin(theta)^2);
```

into:

```
theta_0 = 1:100;
n_eo_theta=n_eo*n_o./sqrt(n_o^2*cos(theta_0).^2+n_eo^2*sin(theta_0).^2);
```

This would run as is, although you should also want to remove the variable "theta" in the for-loop. I.e. simply change

```
n_eo_theta(theta)
```

into

```
n_eo_theta(j)
```

The way of using the "." prefix in the calculations is the furthermost tool for getting rid of for-loops (i.e. using element-wise calculations). For instance; see [element-wise multiplication](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html).

Comment: Yeah, I had suspected this might be the case. I guess I will have to live with at least one for-loop. I did manage to do the same thing with a recursive function but I'm not sure if that is better/worse than a for-loop. Thanks!

Comment: No loops and no recursions are need in the above code.

Comment: I can agree that the first and second for loop (ones iterating i och j) can get removed, but I'm afraid that would require switching into 3d-matrices or cells (which wouldn't improve the code at all). It is not possible to get rid of all for-loops @Kostas, if we assume we don't also want to switch into built in iterative matlab-functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use matrices!!!!

For example, you have the statement:

```
theta=int(j)
```

which is inside a nested loop. You can replace it by:

```
theta = [int(1:points);int(1:points);int(1:points)];
```

or:

```
theta = int(repmat((1:points), 3, 1));
```

Then, you have

```
alfa_n=alfa * n;
```

you can replace it by:

```
alfa_n = alfa .* (0:N_skiv);
```

And have all the calculation done in a row like fashion. That means, instead looping, you will have the values of a loop in a row. Thus, you perform the calculations at the rows using the MATLAB's functionalities and not looping.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had tried rewriting my functions to accept vectors but I wasn't quite sure how to handle the matrix multiplication in the function with a vector as input.

Comment: First of all, everything in MATLAB is matrix. Even a single variable. That's why it is called MAT(rix) LAB(oratory). 

Thus, you don't have to change any of your functions' signatures just the implementation. 

Regarding the latter, you should implement the looping behavior by acting on the rows (or columns) of the matrices. As far I can see, you don't have loop dependencies. You just apply a formula to each "row".

Comment: I know what MATLAB stands for and I am aware of the fact that even single variables are considered matrices. In any case, changing those single variable matrices to 1xn matrices returns an error if the functions are not rewritten to accept the input. As I mentioned above, I tried to do this but it quickly got too complicated for me.

Comment: A good approach would be to do the following in a piece of paper:

1. First identify the actual calculations that you do.
2. Then identify any dependent variables between repetition
3. Design the matrices that you need
4. Understand how calculations from 1 affect each row
5. Assign to each row the values